# Mandrill Mailchimp how to embed an image in email body

Tags: c#, asp.net, mandrill

I want to embed an image in email footer. I have used "LinkedResources" to do this with .NET mail client previously. (`mailObject.AlternateViews.Add(footerImageLinkedResource);`)

But with Mandrill api does not have an Alternate view.

Sample code I tried is as follows with Mandrill,

```
MailChimp.Types.Mandrill.Messages.Message message = new MailChimp.Types.Mandrill.Messages.Message();    
Stream ms = new FileStream(@"C:\sam.jpg", FileMode.Open);
string src = ImageFormatter.GetImageURL(ms);
ms.Close();
message.Html = body + "<p><a href=\"" + websiteUrl + "\"><img alt=\"" + websiteUrl + "\" src=\"" + src + "\" /></a></p>";
```

How can I achieve this task? 
(If the src is given as a URL it works fine, but I want to embed the image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `images` API parameter as per this page:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/25252978-Tips-for-using-images-in-Mandrill-emails

You need to provide the image name, base64-encoded image and the mime-type of the image, then refer to the image by its name in your email's HTML. It might look like this using the .NET Mandrill API wrapper (https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet) (untested):

```
List<Mandrill.image> images = new List<Mandrill.image>();
Mandrill.image img = new Mandrill.image();
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\sam.jpg")
img.content = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData)
img.type = "image/jpeg"
img.name = "image_name"
images.Add(Image)
Email.images = images //(where Email is a Mandrill.EmailMessage)
```

And then in your email you would have code like this:

```
<img src="cid:image_name">
```

Which will show that image by ID that you sent with the email.

Comment: Hi Martin, I included <img src="cid:logo"> in my html template, but when I checked the sent email in mandrill outbound activity, i found the image data didn't get attached properly. Instead, it just show '<img src="cid:logo">' plain text in the html. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "LinkedResources" method still seems to work with Mandrill, when using SMTP to send email.

In case anybody needs to add inline images without Mandrill API, for me it worked with creating an alterate view with some dummy html, and adding the image as linked resource. Here is a snippet:

```
string htmlBody = String.Format("<html><body><img src=\"cid:{0}\" /></body></html>", "myContentId");
AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(imageStream, "image/png");
inline.ContentId = "myContentId";
inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);
emailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

_emailSender.Send(emailMessage);
```

Mandrill will ignore the html body I provided, and will use the configured template. And in that Mandrill template I also write `<img src="cid:myContentId" />`, and it will send the image as inline attachment, with ContentID set.
I didn't find any documentation for this, it is just trial and error.

_emailSender is the .NET SmtpClient, and emailMessage is System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.